# Find minimun with a constraint

Tags: calculus

I need to find the minimum of 
$$ d-c $$
under the constraint 
$$ (1-c)^{14}-(1-d)^{14}=0.95, d>c\geq 0 $$ 
I try to use Lagrange multiplier, given $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, I need to find the minimum of 
$$ G(d,c,\lambda) = d - c - \lambda((1-c)^{14}-(1-d)^{14}-0.95)$$
Taking the partial derivatives over all variables, I obtain the following equation system: 
$$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial c} = - 1 + 14\lambda(1-c)^{13} = 0 $$
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial d} = 1 - 14\lambda(1-d)^{13} $$
$$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial \lambda} = (1-c)^{14}-(1-d)^{14} - 0.95 = 0$$
Which seems to have no solution.
I suppose then it means the extremum must occur at the boundary, when $c = 0$. However, $c=0$ can also be a maximum point.

I'm wondering how should I identify whether it is a minimum or a maximum? 
Thanks!

P.S. I used Mathematica to find the minimum and it says the minimum is c = 0, d = 0.19.

Comment: The boundary $c=0$ should be a point so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, there is exactly two points on the boundary, since constraint should be satisfied., i.e.
\begin{equation*}
(1-d)^{14} = 0.05 \Rightarrow d= 1 \pm \sqrt[14]{0.05}
\end{equation*}

From here, it is obvious which one is minimum, and which one is maximum.

Comment: Thanks! But if there's only one point on the boundary, how should I go?